# Vue.js model binding to a jquery input

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, vue.js

How do you bind an input using vue.js when the input is rendered using a jquery plugin such as datepicker. In my example below the two way binding doesnt work for the jquery colourpicker. When I change the color it doesn't change the corresponding vue value:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Color picker for jQuery</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A very simple jQuery color picker plugin">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.simplecolorpicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.simplecolorpicker-regularfont.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="cars">
      <table>
        <tr v-for="car in cars">
          <td>
            <input name="name" type="text" v-colorpicker="car.name">
          </td>
          <td>
            <select class="colorpicker" name="color" v-model="car.color">
              <option value="#cc6699">#cc6699</option>
              <option value="#993366">#993366</option>
              <option value="#cc3333">#cc3333</option>
               <option value="#336699">#336699</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <pre>{{$data | json }}</pre>

    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.simplecolorpicker.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.13/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#cars',

        data: {
          cars: [{
            name: 'Toyota',
            color: '#cc6699'
          }, {
            name: 'Nissan',
            color: '#336699'
          }]
        }

      });

      $('select.colorpicker').simplecolorpicker({
        picker: true,
        theme: "regularfont"
      });
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

*** UPDATE ****

I've manage to get something working using the following directive, the only problem is when the page first loads, each picker isn't selected with the  correct color as per the cars array - they all load with the first option as selected - do i need to add an onload method to the directive below:

```
  Vue.directive('colorpicker', {
      twoWay: true,
      priority: 1000,

      params: ['options'],

      bind: function () {
        var self = this

        $(this.el)
          .simplecolorpicker({
            picker: true, 
            theme: "regularfont"
          })
          .on('change', function () {
            self.set(this.value)
          })
      },
      update: function (value) {
        $(this.el).val(value).trigger('change')
      },
      unbind: function () {
        $(this.el).off().simplecolorpicker('destroy')
      }
    })
```

Comment: For every car, wouldn't there be a `select.colorpicker` instance? Which one would jquery change? Try generating an id using the car $index and use that selector.

Comment: Also, i tried pasting your code to try it, but chrome throws errors regarding your github files. Could you create a fiddle, in case my previous advice doesn't work?

Comment: the simple color picker is using the css class `colorpicker` to wire it up and yes it is rendered next to each car. The color picker works fine but the two way binding doesn't work. If you look at the data in the pre tag you can see the data value doesnt change when you select different colors.

Comment: you can test on plunker by copying the above html and pasting into the following: http://plnkr.co/edit/VVclW0?p=preview

Comment: simplecolorpicker library requires separate directives to function with JS frameworks. You'll have to make one for Vue. They have one for angular 1.x on their github repo and another for ruby. Trying to replicate the logic, but haven't reached far..

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your vue model to include a selected property, as explained in the vuejs documentation (http://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Select), and an options property (you could use cars as you have it now)

This is how I changed the select:

```
<select name="colorpicker" v-model="selected">
 <option v-for="option in cars" v-bind:value="option.color">
  {{ option.color }}
 </option>
</select>
```

This is how I changed the js:

```
var vueModel = new Vue({
  el: '#cars',

   data: {
     selected: '#cc6699',
     cars: [
       {name: 'Toyota', color: '#cc6699'},
       {name: 'Nissan', color: '#336699'},
       {name: 'Nissan', color: '#333333'}
     ]
   }
});

$('select[name="colorpicker"]')
  .simplecolorpicker({
    'selectColor': '#cc6699',
     picker: true})
   .on('change', function() {
     vueModel.selected = $('select[name="colorpicker"]').val();
 });
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I already have a selected property v-model="car.color"

Comment: Yes @user3324298, you are right, there are problems with including the jquery plugin

Comment: There are no issues with the jquery plugin.

Comment: no errors. The fiddle probably doesn't work because the stylesheet sheets arnt rendering. I dont know how to copy the style sheets to somewhere locally using a fiddle but on my own pc I've copied them and the picker works, its just the two way binding with vue doesnt work.

Comment: Use can test by copying the html above and pasting into the following: http://plnkr.co/edit/VVclW0?p=preview

Comment: I have updated my answer with some code snippets, I hope this helps, I was not able to use the plunkr you suggested, as I got a lot of errors

Comment: @Nora This won't work properly.. he's got multiple instances of the color picker, your jquery will only change the first instance.